# finds a random destination point from current location is within the given distance GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

i am making an iOS map using google maps.i want to plot a way on google maps from current location to any random destination is within given distance.

means the app finds a random destination point that is within the given distance(e.g MAYBE 8 KM OR 15KM ) (doesn't have to be accurately within the distance as long as it is on the sidewalk). 
RANDOM DESTINATION is must on route,so user can run from starting point to designation point(Random point).

How can a get a designation point from current location on google Maps.any idea ..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a arc4random_uniform() to calculate a value that's like 200,000 times bigger than that maximum amount you want your point to move away from the user's current location. Then subtract half that max value from the random number and divide by half the max value.

double scale = 100000;

double maxNorthSouthChange = 2,000; //2,000 meters, 2k
double randomNorthSouthChange = arc4random_uniform(maxNorthSouthChange*2*scale)/(2*scale)-
  maxNorthSouthChange*scale; 
//randomNorthSouthChange should now range from -maxNorthSouthChange to +maxNorthSouthChange;

double maxEastWestChange = 2,000; //2,000 meters, 2k
double randomEastWesthange = arc4random_uniform(maxEastWestChange*2*scale)/(2*scale)-
  maxEastWestChange*scale; 
//randomEastWesthange should now range from -maxEastWestChange to + maxEastWestChange;

Get the lat/long of the user's location. Calculate the number of kilometers  per degree of longitude for your current latitude. (The number of kilometers per degree of latitude doesn't change.)

Use those values to convert your random change values to lat/long scale, and add them to the user's current location.

The above code will create a random location inside a square box around the user. The max distance at the corners of that box will be more than the max you specify. IF you wanted to make the max random change in location be the same in all directions, you'd need to rewrite the code above to use trig, but you said the amount didn't have to be exact.

Comment: thanks Duncan C for replying

but RANDOM DESTINATION is must on route,because user have run from starting point to designation point(Random point)